# Access to field parameters in elasticsearh 2.0.0

Tags: elasticsearch

We noticed since we upgraded to elasticsearch 2.0.0, to access to a field of an index, we have to change our request using @fields.myfield1 instead of directly myfield1 as we used to do in ES 1.7.2.

Even in the plugin "Head", I can see that all the field names are preceded with @fields.

Is that a change in the way of accessing fields in ES 2.0.0 or a specificity of our cluster or requests ?

Thank you for your attention

Comment: Are you referring to writing queries against ES 2 or parsing the response with one of the client libraries?

Comment: Take a look at the breaking changes: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_mapping_changes.html#_fields_cannot_be_referenced_by_short_name I think you're referring to the fact that fields can no longer be referenced by short name

Comment: I am referring to the fact that when I am doing a query in Sense (the plugin), let's say an aggregation, I have to write @fileds.color to access to the field and not only color. I've read the Breaking changes and couldn't find where that change in the way of accessing fields in queries is mentionned.